# How to install an application that depends on libqca2-plugin-ossl which has been replaced by libqca2-plugins

Tags: package-management, dependencies

Am trying to install `fingerprint-gui` in Ubuntu 18.04. When using

```
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

an error message states:

```
fingerprint-gui :
  Depends: libqca2-plugin-ossl but it is not installable.
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When using

```
sudo apt get install libqca2-plugin-ossl
```

the message states that this file has been replaced by `libqca2-plugins`. I have installed `libqca2-plugins`.  How can I change the dependency to in order to install `fingerprint-gui`?

Comment: ...trying to install from where? Is there a guide or a howto you've followed?